# VIM.. Yank multiple rows based on regex

Tags: vim

Here's my situation I have numerous SQL rows like the following.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
DELETE FROM blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
DELETE FROM blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
DELETE FROM blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
DELETE FROM blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
DELETE FROM blah
```

I want to rearrange it using VIM to

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
SET IDENTITY_INSERT blah
DELETE FROM blah
DELETE FROM blah
DELETE FROM blah
```

now I know I could write a simple python script to accomplish this quickly but I'm trying to up my VIM skills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use g command:

```
:g/^DELETE/m$
```

This will move (m) all lines starting with DELETE to the end of the file ($).

Comment: You could also use `:v/DELETE/m$`

Comment: or @Mud, if I want to learn advanced `:g` or `:v` kung-fu, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

the following does not use any regex...

```
:sort!
```

details : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Sort_lines

Comment: This changes the original order, which may or may not be what the OP wants.